# PHP: escape non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex, escaping, alphanumeric

I'm trying to port a script that I wrote in bash some time ago into PHP. One particular line is about escaping all non-alphanumeric characters.

In bash, I was able to do it as a one-liner as follows:

```
echo "aaa bbb::" | sed 's/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\\\1/g'
# => aaa\ bbb\:\:
```

The closest I got in PHP was with this:

```
echo preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/','\\\','aaa bbb::');
# => aaa\bbb\\
```

However I'm struggling to reuse my regex group inside `preg_replace` (I tried \1 and $1).

**Can someone help me get this PHP one-liner right please?**

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but why you need to escape all non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: because I'm generating filters for `mod_rewrite` and it doesn't really like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/',"\\\\$1",'aaa bbb::');
//output => aaa\ bbb\:\:
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `[^[:alnum:]]` to represent all non-alphanumeric characters in your locale and don't forget to double-double escape your backslashes:

```
$ cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?
echo preg_replace('/([^[:alnum:]])/', '\\\\$1', 'aaa bbb::');
?>

$ ./test.php 
aaa\ bbb\:\:
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `[^[:alnum:]]` ***and*** using single quotes! :P

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('~([^a-zA-Z0-9])~', '\\\\$1', 'aaa bbb::');
```